# How is case end date set?

Tags: civicase

I've just found this on one site. I have some (not all) cases of a given case type. There case status is set to a "closed" status. But the case does not have an end date.

I cannot find a way to update the case end date from the manage case screen.

This seems to effect cases where status was changed between July 17 and October 18
Cases amended before and since have an end date recorded

Cases with other closed statusses all have end dates as expected.

I guess I can find the related case status change activities, and then manually adjust the case end dates from cpanel (only a dozen or so cases affected).

Just left scratching my head, is all.

Comment: How about trying to resave the case activity? i.e edit the case activity and saving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a profile defined that has case status in it? Possibly somebody did a case search and then chose Update Multiple Cases from the actions dropdown. A test on dmaster.demo shows this doesn't update the end date automatically or file a change case status activity on the case.

You could also change the status without the end date from the api explorer, but I doubt your users did that.

Another possibility is you have no case status defined that has "Status Class" set to 'Closed'. Under Administer - CiviCase - Case Statuses. In the database this is the grouping field in the civicrm_option_value table.

Comment: Just checked. No case profiles in use. And no access to api for users.

Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Added another answer, which maybe jives with your comment that re-saving the activity does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you resave the status it will update the case end date. On Manage case screen click on pencil icon just next to 'Status: Resolved'. Save the form without doing any changes.(Please check the activity date time field under Activity Details  if it has correct date).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep,

I tried that didn't make any difference.

Craig

Answer (score 1):

The case end date can be reset by clicking the pencil icon on case status. As Pradeep says re-save the Case Status change activity leaving the case status as Closed (creates a new change case status activity) But before you do that open the Activity detail section and change the date of the activity to the new Case End date required.

Comment: Thanks Olly, I posted this so long ago I can't even remember which site was causing the problem.